# Can I bind a parameter after an underscore in a rails 2.3 route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

In order to maintain backward compatibility, we need to map /sitemap_1234000.xml to the sitemap controller with 1234000 passed as an ID.  I tried

```
map.connect '/sitemap_:id.xml', :controller => 'sitemap',
                            :action => 'show'
```

but then when I do

```
assert_routing '/sitemap_1234000.xml', :controller => 'sitemap', 
                                       :action => 'show',
                                       :id => "1234000"
```

I get told that no route exists for '/sitemap_1234000.xml'.  Can I bind a parameter after an underscore in a rails 2.3 route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around inside rails, this is what I came up with:

```
config/initializers/bound_parameter_after_underscore.rb

module ActionController
  module Routing
    class RouteBuilder
      def initialize_with_bound_parameter_after_underscore
        initialize_without_bound_parameter_after_underscore
        @nonseparator_regexp = /\A([^#{Regexp.escape(separators.join)}:\*]+)/
      end

      alias_method_chain :initialize, :bound_parameter_after_underscore
    end
  end
end
```

That stops colon and asterisk from appearing in static segments.  Previously the regex which looks for static segments was consuming all of `sitemap_:id`; now it consumes `sitemap_` and leaves `:id` which is then recognised as you would hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards:

```
map.connect '/sitemap_(*id).xml, :controller=>'sitemap', :action=>'show'
```

Then params[:id] should give you what you want.

Not tested - let me know if this works

Comment: won't that stick it into an array?